# Removing PowerPoint slide titles

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I need a piece of VB code that will remove all 'titles' from numerous PowerPoint slides.  I am using a software to output SPSS data that has a unchangeable default setting to output title headings and I need these removed across 100 of slides.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we're not a code generating service.  You need to demonstrate that you've put in some effort yourself.  Show what code you've tried or what research you've done (with links) and ask a *specific* question about what's not working right.

Comment: Have a look at [Shape.Title Property (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.title).

Answer (score 0):

With Andrew's pointer to the correct method, it's only a few minutes further to this (VBA, not VB.NET, but should be translate-able):

```
Sub DeleteTitles()

Dim oSl As Slide

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    ' Run this once with the IMMEDIATE window visible
    ' Verify that what YOU see as titles are actually what PPT sees as titles
    Debug.Print oSl.SlideIndex & vbTab & oSl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

    ' If all's well, comment out the Debug.Print line and uncomment this:
    'oSl.Shapes.Title.Delete

Next

End Sub
```

Do note that what may look like a title to us isn't always a title as far as PPT is concerned. If you put PPT in Outline view, the title (as PPT sees it) will be next to the little slide icons. If there's nothing there, then there's no title and the code above won't work.